# Is this sentence 2nd conditional or past tense?

Tags: tense

> No sooner had he said the word, when clatter, clatter, rustle, rustle,
>   what should come down the chimney but a link of the finest black
>   pudding the heart of man could wish for.
>
> **If the woodman stared, the goodwife stared three times as much.
>   'What's all this?" says she.**

This is from a English fairy tale "The Three Wishes". Is "If the woodman stared, the goodwife stared three times as much." is 2nd conditional? But it doesn't have a word "would". Does it make sense just as past tense? And why is it "says she"? Does it mean "she would say"? Could you teach me?

Answer (score 2):

**If**

It's not a conditional.

One of the definitions of "if" given by [Cambridge](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/if) is "although":

> *They're great kids, even **if** they can be demanding.*
>
> literary *It was a hot, **if** windy day.*

**Says she**

When quoting direct speech, the verb "say" can appear in multiple positions, all correct:

> "Hello," David said.
>
> "Hello," said David.
>
> David said, "Hello."
>
> Said David, "Hello."

The last is rare.  The first three are all quite common where the subject is a noun, but where the subject is a pronoun, the "he said" word order is much more frequent than "said he".

"Says she" is therefore a relatively unusual way of saying "she says".

Here it seems to represent the historic present - i.e. it is the present tense but it is used to tell a story.

Comment: Thank you for your helpful answer. That is to say, they are all fact?

Comment: Indeed they are.